# Unable to cancel task

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365-v9, dynamics-crm-uci

### Issue: Timeout while canceling Task on Unified Interface

**Tool**: **Dynamics 365 CRM, Version 1612 (9.0.2.192) (DB 9.0.2.192) online**

**Problem**: We have a field on appointment form, has the value *true* and *False*. While saving we check if the value is true then, opens a New task window and we set a lookup(we created this lookup) like below,

```
var entityFormOptions = {};
entityFormOptions["entityName"] = "task";


formParameters["cmd_associatedmeeting"] = formContext.data.entity.getId().replace('{', '').replace('}', '');

formParameters["subject"] = "Created From " + getEntityType(ExecutionContext) + ": " + formContext.getAttribute(formElements_meeting.subject).getValue();
// Open the form.
Xrm.Navigation.openForm(entityFormOptions, formParameters).then(

function (success) {
if (window.console && console.error) console.log(success);
},

function (error) {
if (window.console && console.error) console.log(error);
});
```

We save a task record and synchronous workflow will create a Connection Record(We are using Connection entity to associate this record with appointment). Connection record contains

Connect To: Appointment

Connection From: Task

We click Close Task as Cancelled and we get an issue on Mobile (It works well in the browser). We are using UCI based app to use CRM in Mobile.

Error:

```
Operation timed out. 
Key = [subject,cmd_iscloned,statuscode,description,regardingobjectid,cmd_associatedevent,cmd_associatedmeeting,statecode,ownerid,modifiedby,param_actGuid,statecode]; 
ContextString = Key: a7edbe81-875d-e811-a959-000d3a1c5096; 
ColumnSet: [subject,cmd_iscloned,statuscode,description,regardingobjectid,cmd_associatedevent,cmd_associatedmeeting,statecode,ownerid,modifiedby,param_actGuid,statecode]; RetrievalStrategy: remote
```

it is getting completed but not canceled.

EDIT: If I cancel the Appointment record, I will be able to cancel the task.

Require help!

Comment: Create a ticket with MS, we are working with them on multiple tickets like this. Mostly known issues and fix will be on the way in next build..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were using Form Parameters to set lookup on task, we removed the form parameter and did it another way. and it worked. Issue no longer exist!

Comment: Another way? Pls share more details which will help others.

Comment: I have written javascript - it is there in the question only. Earlier we were using Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("contact", null, parameters);. Now we are using Xrm.Navigation.openForm which is UCI compatible. and removed Parameter from form properties.